# Запятые в сложносочиненных предложениях 3

Tags: пунктуация

Объясните, пожалуйста, про запятые в сложносочиненных предложениях!

Осенью температура в цехах понижается и начинает возражать гидравлика.

В этом предложении общий второстепенный член - обстоятельство времени *осенью*, значит, запятая не нужна... Но второе простое предложение как будто является следствием первого - температура понижается и *поэтому* начинает возражать гидравлика. Значит, все же нужна запятая?

Comment: Гидравлика не может возражать. Возражать может как минимум кибернетика.  Это вероятно калька с английского "acts up". Некрасиво.

Comment: @ddbug  Уверяю вас, гидравлика в плане возражений ничем не хуже кибернетики.

Comment: И какая калька с какого английского?.. Пишет конструктор воспоминания о советских временах...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот если бы слова ПОЭТОМУ, ТОГДА присутствовали, мы бы поставили запятую, потому что появилось бы другое, преобладающее обстоятельство, но в данном случае оно общее-обстоятельство времени, других нет, нет и запятой.

Если бы здесь преобладало значение следствия, предложение бы оформили как бессоюзное с тире.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Цвета у нас у всех сменились... Давно не была...)))

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с Людмилой.
Добавлю. Здесь неудачно использовано слово "возражать" в значении "отказывать".  Но дело не в кибернетике, а в том, что можно понять неправильно, как отсылку к теории, "возражающей" против каких-то положений другой теории, а не элементарный отказ гидравлических механизмов от перегрузки.